# Click through UIButton - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have two UIButtons one on top of the other. The first one has a custom class which implements a visual feedback and the other button has an onClick event method which calls a function.

How can I get the onClick event of the second button which is under the first button?

*I need to have two buttons so I can customise the touch area and the size of the visual feedback.*

Answer (score 3):

Subclassing `UIButton` is not suggested to start with :) If you need to have a Visual Feedback effect, you can have a `UIView` and add a `tapGesture` recogniser. And on detecting tap you can do

**Swift**

```
    let touchPoint = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: your_view)
    if your_inner_button.frame.contains(touchPoint) {
        your_inner_button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

**Objective-C**

```
    CGPoint point = [self.tapGesture locationInView:self];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, point)) {
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
```

Above one does not make much sense, because if you have already detected the tap and figured out that touch is inside the frame of your requirement, why would you even trigger button click, call `performSelector` directly.That way you don't need a button n a view rather all you need is just a `View`

Just to clarify that it is possible to do what you want,

If for some unknown reasons, you can't do it and you are forced (at gun point I guess :P) to use two buttons on top of each other, you can always handover touch to button below by using `hitTest`

**Swift**

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if your_inner_button.frame.contains(point) {
               return your_inner_button
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(your_inner_button.frame, point)) {
        return your_inner_button
    }
    return nil;
}
```

For this to work you will have to pass the below button reference to top button, which shouldn't be a problem because you anyway have a subclass for top button :) Is that code smell? For me yes, but will it serve your need? Yes it does :)

Hope it helps